# Why do I have SyphonInject on my Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

I don't ever recall installing anything called SyphonInject. I just noticed that I have it in the Launchpad and it sounds menacing.

Is this something that comes preinstalled in a MacBook?

Is it okay to completely remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this something that comes preinstalled in a MacBook?

No. It is a [3rd party app](https://github.com/zakk4223/SyphonInject).

> Is it okay to completely remove it?

Yes, it is okay to remove it if you don't use it. It must have been installed by the previous owner.

If this MacBook is a shared computer and it's possible that some other user may be using the app, it's safe to leave it.

Further relevant discussions on Web:

- [SyphonInject what is it](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8263715)
- [Is Syphon Inject a "safe" program that's used in OBS?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Twitch/comments/37kbru/is_syphon_inject_a_safe_program_thats_used_in_obs/)

Comment: thank you for answering, what concerns me is that there was no previous owner and I don't remember installing it.

Comment: @Daniel Is it possible that someone else used your MacBook and installed it? Did you purchase a used or a brand new MacBook?

Comment: From what I saw it might also be used by another developer and installed as a part of another app. But Nimesh knows what he is talking about and I would also say probably safe to remove.

Comment: No, I downloaded OBS, but have yet to learn how to use it and if SyphonInject is a dependency of OBS, I may just have broken OBS because I deleted SyphonInject. They should probably mention that when downloading.

Comment: @Daniel Reinstalling the software should fix it IMO.

Comment: @NimeshNeema, yeah I might as well just completely remove OBS and reinstall it. I did it a couple of months ago because I will need it for a project, but I have not gotten to that part of it yet.

Comment: It is installed by OBS, but the developer says on its GitHub repo that the app doesn't work anymore with Mojave.
Source: https://github.com/zakk4223/SyphonInject